# Checking for Testicular Cancer

Tags: halacha, choleh-sick, parts-of-the-body

[May a man look at and/or touch his reproductive organ while bathing?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/88140/may-a-man-look-at-and-or-touch-his-reproductive-organ-while-bathing) made me think of another related question.

It has been medically suggested that men do a regular self-check for testicular cancer.  Would it be Halachically appropriate to perform such a regular check, being that this involves examining the testicles carefully using one's hands (as well as looking at them)?

An answer to this question should be a thorough treatment of the subject, covering many of the Halachic bases (such as touching the scrotum in general, cases of fear, the factors that the [statistics](https://www.cancer.net/cancer-types/testicular-cancer/statistics) may play, etc.), or a source that directly discusses this issue.

Comment: For anyone who wants to write a comprehensive answer, I would suggest looking up and reading through שו"ת ציץ אליעזר חלק יט סימן ד, which addresses a very similar question.  If no one else wants to do it, at some point I will write it up...

Comment: you can always get married and then it will be ok, (the tzis eliyezer http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14518&st=&pgnum=15 )

Comment: @Hazoriz thanks for the link. You're right about getting married (presumably ishto imo too), although thats obviously not a real solution to the problem... :)

Comment: it is the real solution to many problems, people (are very influenced by the non Jews) do not want to admit it (end of https://www.sefaria.org/Kohelet_Rabbah.9.9?lang=bi and https://www.sefaria.org/Yevamot.62b.13?lang=bi )

Answer (score 1):

Shulchan Aruch in Orach Chaim siman 3 rules that touching ones scrotum is allowed even for someone who is not married.

Mishna Berurah explains that his member will not be warmed by this action.

The discussion there is to help aim while urinating, but this is at least as important. I only mention this as perhaps one can argue touching ones scrotum for no purpose is not allowed.

> יד.יזהר שלא יאחוז באמה וישתין אם לא מעטרה ולמטה מפני שמוציא שכבת זרע לבטלה אלא אם כן הוא נשוי ומדת חסידות ליזהר אפילו הנשוי:
>
> טו. אפילו מי שאינו נשוי מותר לסייע בביצים:

Comment: "I only mention this as perhaps one can argue touching ones scrotum for no purpose is not allowed." certainly that can be argued. Also, perhaps one can argue on "this is at least as important", as if you learn the sugya there, the heter is only so the urine will not fall straight down, and there are significant reasons as to why that is very important, see there.

Comment: Additionally, it is clear that touching is different than rubbing or rolling, or many of the actions done during such an examination

Comment: Even more so, Shulchan Aruch says that an unmarried person may NOT touch his scrotum in EH siman 23:4, see SA and Biur Hagra there.

Comment: Your quote from eh is incorrect. It specifically says ama, not beitzim. אסור לאדם שאינו נשוי לשלוח ידיו במבושיו כדי שלא יבא לידי הרהור ואפי׳ מתחת טבורו לא יכניס ידו שמא יבא לידי הרהור ואם השתין מים לא יאחוז באמה וישתין ואם היה נשוי מותר ובין נשוי ובין שאינו נשוי לא יושיט ידו לאמה כלל אלא בשעה שהוא צריך לנקביו (ועיין בא״ח סימן ג׳) :

Comment: The significant reason in b.h. to allow touching the scrotum is to not to be motzi laz that his children are not his. A safek of pikuach nefesh is more important than a safek of laz.

Comment: Chikuch is only applicable on the ama proper as seen in e.h. there (and the sugya in yevamos) chikuch of beitzim will never cause a seminal discharge.

Comment: @hazoriz but there is a limit to what that expression includes. You can touch your knees and your bum. Shulcham Aruch in o.ch. explains to us that beitzim are not included in the prohibition. There is no mitzvah to pretend there is a contradiction between e.h. and o.ch.

Comment: @user6591 to my poor understanding it seems, that ama is regarding never touching, see this translation halacha 23 here http://www.chabad.org/960669/

Comment: @user6591 o.h. is regarding the time of urination, e.h. regarding ama is even when urinating , and other parts when not urinating

Comment: @user6591, my quote from EH is bang on. Reread the first sentence - how do you translate  "Mevushav"? And also, being motzi Laaz is serious enough to have a hava Amina to allow even touching the Amah itself, and it would be a huge stretch to say that this case would be safek pikuach nefesh.

Comment: I already explained the mevushav issue to hazoriz @רבות

Comment: And again, there is never a fear of zera livatala from touching beitzim. As mentioned in mishna berurah.

Comment: @user6591 and I don't understand your explanation.  Firstly because I referenced the biur hagra.  Secondly, because of Devarim 25:11, which clearly means scrotum, Thirdly, because Rambam and Tur (see BY OC there) skip out codifying the Heter of touching the scrotum to help the urination.

Comment: @user6591 "And again, there is never a fear of zera livatala from touching beitzim. As mentioned in mishna berurah." and that is a fourth proof that Mevushav means scrotum, because the Shulchan Aruch says that it leads to HIRHUR

Comment: I'm sorry there is not a thorough answer necessary. If you want to assume the shulchan aruch contradicted himself and assume that since the hetter he allowed in shulchan aruch wasn't mentioned in his earlier work of the b.y. that is up to you. The shulchan aruch along with the explanation in m.b. says this is allowed. Sometimes the easiest answers are overlooked. I'm sorry if that is disappointing. @רבות

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/71028/discussion-between---and-user6591).